# Суммирование повторяющихся значений HashMap

Tags: java, map, hashmap

На данном этапе программа суммирует даже не повторяющиеся значения дважды

Текст файла access3.log:

```
1360427766.547    160 192.168.50.8 TCP_DENIED/403 3882 CONNECT mail.radar.imgsmail.ru:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1360427773.778    163 192.168.50.8 TCP_DENIED/403 3876 CONNECT www.odnoklassniki.ru:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1360427783.739    405 192.168.252.100 TCP_MISS/200 753 GET http://swa.mail.ru/cgi-bin/counters? - SOURCEHASH_PARENT/192.168.254.4 application/x-javascript
```

Код программы:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\java\\access3.log");

        Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
                String ip = data[2];
                String bytes = data[4];
                // получаем другие данные по индексу в том порядке, в каком они идут в логах

                map.put(ip, Integer.parseInt(bytes)); // заполняем map, подставляем значения, какие хотим в ключ и значение
                if(map.containsKey(ip)) //здесь начинаем смотреть были ли уже в карте такие же ключи(ip) и суммируем для них bytes
                    map.put(ip, Integer.parseInt(bytes) + map.get(ip));
                else
                    map.put(ip, Integer.parseInt(bytes));
            }
        }

                System.out.println(map);
            }
        }
```

Должно быть:

```
{192.168.252.100=753, 192.168.50.8=7758}
```

У меня выводится:

```
{192.168.252.100=1506, 192.168.50.8=7752}
```

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что предварительно заполнение вам не нужно.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
    String ip = data[2];
    String bytes = data[4];
                
    if(map.containsKey(ip)) 
         map.put(ip, Integer.parseInt(bytes) + map.get(ip));
    else
         map.put(ip, Integer.parseInt(bytes));
}
```

Однако в вашем случае лучше воспользоваться уже имеющейся стандартной функцией `merge`

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
    String ip = data[2];
    String bytes = data[4];
                
    map.merge(ip, Integer.parseInt(bytes), Integer::sum);
}
```